# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group in tst file

Tags: .net, angular, typescript

I am trying to check a condition in the tst (typescript generator) file in my C# application . I am getting the error Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group. The error that I am getting is in the ObserveResponse where i am checking the HasParameters

```
bool HasParameters(Method m) => m.Parameters != null  && m.Parameters.Count > 0 ? true : false;

string ObserveResponse(Method m)
   {
    var api = (Class)m.Parent;
    if ((api.Attributes.Any(i=>i.Name=="AllowAnonymous")) && HasParameters ) return ",{observe: 'response'}";
    if (api.Attributes.Any(i=>i.Name=="Authorize")) return '';
     if (m.Attributes.Any(i=>i.Name=="AllowAnonymous")) return ",{observe: 'response'}";
    if (m.Attributes.Any(i=>i.Name=="Authorize")) return '';
    return "#ERROR";
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HasParameters is a method so you need to call it (with a parameter - presumably m):

```
bool HasParameters(Method m) => m.Parameters != null  && m.Parameters.Count > 0 ? true : false;

string ObserveResponse(Method m)
   {
    var api = (Class)m.Parent;
    if ((api.Attributes.Any(i=>i.Name=="AllowAnonymous")) && HasParameters(m) ) return ",{observe: 'response'}";
    if (api.Attributes.Any(i=>i.Name=="Authorize")) return '';
     if (m.Attributes.Any(i=>i.Name=="AllowAnonymous")) return ",{observe: 'response'}";
    if (m.Attributes.Any(i=>i.Name=="Authorize")) return '';
    return "#ERROR";
   }
```

(change HasParameters to HasParameters(m) in the ObserverResponse method)